# How to work on kernel with an embedded device?

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, embedded

Right now, I'm compiling with `printk`'s, copy the resulting kernel to a USB stick, mounting the USB stick on the device, mounting the partition that contains the kernel, copying the new kernel from the USB stick to the partition, `reboot`ing, then inspecting the trace by capturing the `dmesg` output to a file.

On workstation:

```
make my-kernel
cp new_kernel /path/to/usb/stick
```

On embedded device:

```
mount /dev/sda1/ /mnt
mount kernelpartition /tmp/kernel
cp /mnt/new_kernel /tmp/kernel
sync
umount /tmp/kernel
umount /dev/sda1
reboot

dmesg > mytrace
less mytrace
```

Is it supposed to this painful to develop?  I don't understand how any meaningful amount of non-trivial kernel code is ever developed.

Comment: No, it is not supposed to be that painful.  First it will be well worth the time invested to get a serial port from your embedded device connected back to your development host, and get console messages on it.  Then you really want to find a way - tftp, some vendor-unique USB bootloader, an add on bootloader like U-Boot, etc to more efficiently load your new builds onto the target.

Comment: You could always try using a virtual machine or emulator like QEMU (if one exists for your embedded platform).

Comment: I once created a minimal working kernel that was installed on the device which only had the sole purpose of loading a new kernel over USB and kexec'ing it. Loading a new kernel was just as easy as rebooting the device and loading a new one over USB. Very easy to automate. You may want to try that if you can't mess with the bootloader or have an emulator you can use.

Comment: Take a look at `fastboot` mode of u-boot. It's what I'm using on my work on daily basis. Paired with `adb` (or just writing commands to serial console) it can allow you to fully automate the whole flashing process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best workflow is going to depend on the capabilities of the device you are working with. Often they will have a bootloader with options to boot from a network or serial port.

I'm doing some embedded development also, and here's what I came up with. The device I am working with has some built in flash which by default it boots from, but also has a USB port and an SD Card slot. It has a fairly primitive bootloader.

- On the USB port I have connected a wifi dongle. I make sure that I compile the kernels with the needed modules to get the USB dongle up and running.
- I have built a minimal kernel and root filesystem which I have flashed onto the device. This kernel has the option `CONFIG_KEXEC` enabled. The root filesystem has kexec tools. I build the system using [buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/).
- When this system starts, it attempts to mount the SDCARD and checks to see if it can find a kernel in the root directory. If it can, then it uses [kexec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kexec) to boot this second kernel. This is done using a custom init script that I have written.

If you don't have an SD Card slot on your device, you could probably do something similar with a USB memory stick.

With this setup, I can just use sftp to transfer a new kernel image onto the sdcard, and kexec to boot it. It saves me the hassle of reflashing the device each time I change the kernel.